# Pass encrypted variable between browser windows in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm desperately trying to pass a variable between browser windows. I have a php page (test.php) which opens another page (another.php) in new window. I also have some variable that needs to be encrypted/decrypted and passed WITH encryption password. I've created a session like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = array(
    'var1' => $encryption_password, 
    'var2' => $some_encrypted_stuff
);
```

But of course in new window 'test' session is NULL. I've tried different options, but all failed. I do can create a file and write data there, but this doesn't seem secure to me.

Can anybody give me a working example for this issue? Can't find anything by myself.

**UPDATE**

OK, my main task is to encrypt variable in one php file and decrypt in another. There's one condition tho: encryption password can NOT be read from initial storing place by 2nd php file - only by the the 1st one.

Comment: have you called session_start(); before getting the $_SESSION['test'] in another.php?

Comment: I would point out that if you are storing the decryption key/password in `$_SESSION` along with the encrypted string, there is little value to encrypting it in the first place.

Comment: This will be security by obscurity instead of real security. See Michael Berkowski comment

Comment: @KernelFolla, I surely did. I even tried to set session cookie path - still no go.

Comment: @The Disintegrator, OK, I'm not super good in securing stuff. How can I encrypt/decrypt variable, considering that I can't get the password from initial place and should pass it somehow?

Comment: Use the session to store a token and nothing more than a token. Store on db whatever you have to pass associated with that particular token. When you have your next request it will pass the token back to the server. Read the token from session, search for it on db, fech, use, destroy from db so it's not reused. This way, the actual variable never left the server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, writing it to a file is probably NOT a good approach. You're trying to achieve a variable retrieval, and nothing more.
I'm not sure why your test variable is null. I just tried making this test myself and I could access everything just fine.
Your code that you provided SHOULD be writing the data to the session variable. First, be sure you're not killing the session somewhere later in that first script. Second, double and triple check your code to access the session variable. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell, but on the second page my only guess is that you're either misspelling the access to the variable, or you're forgetting to **start the session again!**
Here is the code for both of my files:

### First page:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = array('var1' => "somevalue", 'var2' => "someothervalue");

?>
<a href='other.php'>Go</a>
```

---

### Second page:

```
<?
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>
```

That works fine for me- I get the full session variable spat back out. Give it a shot and let us know if you're still having issues (with more of your code so we can better understand whats up). Good luck!

Comment: maybe my problem is in Joomla. I'm saving session in it's framework and then trying to get the session data outside of it.

Comment: Ahhh- perhaps. I haven't used Joomla- I was unaware that it may save session data in a different way. Either way I would call PHP's native session functions if that is an issue. Also, it occurred to me that perhaps sessions aren't enabled in your php install? Double check that as well.